# rspec - Newly instantiated record is nil according to assigns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_super_admin!

  def new
    @thecategory = Category.new
    @thebrands = Brand.all
    render "categories/new"
  end
end
```

In my test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CategoriesController, type: :controller do

  before(:all) do
   @the_super_admin = createLoggedInSuperAdmin
  end

  context "#new" do

    it "instantiates new category" do
      get :new

      expect(assigns(:thecategory)).to be_a_new(Category)
    end
  end
end
```

it keeps on telling me `expected nil to be a kind of Model` and when I inspect it with pry assigns(:themodel) shows as nil

I haven't been able to find any answers that help me with this situation

Comment: What type of test do you use? Is it a capybara test?

Comment: which rails version? `assigns` in controller tests have been deprecated recently.

Comment: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html

Comment: rails version is 4.2.4

Comment: this should just work. is this pseudo code? what is the real code? maybe a typo or you are requesting the wrong controller/action? some logs?

Comment: I added more code copied from the controller and test, and the authentication is working having been checked in another test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was an idiot, the `createLoggedInSuperAdmin` call should have been wrapped in `before(:each)` instead of `before(:all)`, that was why the authentication was working for the first test but failing on the second one